# fgetline_alloc An involved C function for reading lines of arbitrary length

Tags: c

**Prototype:**

```
char *fgetline_alloc( FILE *fp, bool flush, int *nchars, bool eolend );
```

I realize this C99 function may be a bit more involved than expected, hence asking for reviews before using it for real (it's tested, but not extensively). I'll post the source code first, followed by detailed description (which I removed from the source code). I am leaving it in (simplified) debug mode.

I'm also providing quite a few sample-use examples, at the end of the post.

Briefly, the general idea is to return the input as a dynamically allocated c-string (`nul`-terminated buffer of `char`s). `flush` may be set to `true` for interactive input validation in a loop, from `stdin`. `eolend` specifies whether the result will end with EOL or not. `nchars` specifies either the max count of `char`s to be read (positive value), or an initial alloc-ahead size in `char`s (0 or negative value). It also passes back the count of successfully read `char`s. For details, please see the **Details** section below the source code.

If cleared, I intend to also make a `wchar_t` version of it.

Besides anything else you spot, I'd be interested in your opinions about:

- guarding against passed-in overflow of `*nchars` (is it possible? if
  so is it worth it?)
- my approach of preventing `int` overflow for the params of `malloc()` and `realloc()`
- `realloc()`ing the resulting `buf` to its exact size at the end (I currently don't)

Thanks in advance to anyone taking the time to review this.

### Source Code

```
/* tab space: 4 (regular, not spaces) */

#include <stdio.h>      // for debug messages
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <stdbool.h>    // C99 - bool, true, false
#include <limits.h>     // C99 - for INT_MAX, etc
#include <errno.h>

#define MYDEBUG 1
#if MYDEBUG
    #define DBGMSG( ... )\
    do{\
        fprintf(stderr, "*** %s(): ", __func__ );\
        fprintf( stderr, __VA_ARGS__ );\
    }while(0)
#endif

// -----------------------------------------------
// Read a line from an already open text-stream, and Return it as a dynamically
// allocated c-string. Return NULL on failure (errno is also set). The caller
// is responsible for freeing the returned c-string.
// NOTE: Description details removed for brevity.
//
char *fgetline_alloc( FILE *fp, bool flush, int *nchars, bool eolend )
{
    errno = 0;

    // sanity checks and early exits
    if ( !fp ) {
        DBGMSG( "invalid stream\n" );
        errno = EDOM;
        goto fail;
    }
    if ( ferror(fp) ) {
        DBGMSG( "stream error\n" );
        goto fail;
    }
    if ( feof(fp) ) {
        DBGMSG( "already at EOF\n" );
        goto fail;
    }

    // This can't handle passed-in wrap-around overflow, but with sane values
    // it quits before passing an overflowed param to malloc() later on. The max
    // initially allocated size is abs(*nchars)+1+1 chars when eolend is true
    // (the 2nd +1 is for `\0'), so here we actually define the sane domain for
    // *nchars' to [INT_MIN+2, INT_MAX-2] inclusive.
    if ( nchars ) {
        if ( *nchars > 0 && 2 > (INT_MAX - *nchars) ) {
            DBGMSG( "int arg too big (*nchars=%d)\n", *nchars );
            errno = EDOM;
            goto fail;
        }
        if ( *nchars < 0 && -2 < (INT_MIN - *nchars) ) {
            DBGMSG( "int arg too small (*nchars=%d)\n", *nchars );
            errno = EDOM;
            goto fail;
        }
    }

    // distinguish fixed mode (true) from alloc-ahead mode (false)
    bool ncharsFixed = ( nchars && *nchars > 0 );

    // # of chars to allocate (either fixed or initial alloc-ahead)
    int _nchars = 128;              // default alloc-ahead (*nchars == 0)
    if ( nchars ) {
        if ( *nchars < 0 ) {        // user-defined alloc-ahead
            _nchars = -(*nchars);
        }
        else if ( *nchars > 0 ) {   //fixed *nchars (no alloc-ahead)
            _nchars = *nchars;
        }
    }

    // initial alloc size depends on eolend (but always +1 for nul-terminator)
    char *buf = malloc( eolend ? _nchars+1+1 : _nchars+1 );
    if ( !buf ) {
        DBGMSG( "failed to alloc %d bytes\n", eolend ? _nchars+1+1 : _nchars+1 );
        goto fail;
    }

    // read chars into buf until EOL/EOF, or until *nchars if in fixed mode
    int i = 0;                  // count of successfully read chars
    int c = EOF;
    while ( (c=fgetc(fp)) != '\n' && c != EOF ) {
        if ( i == _nchars ) {
            // fixed *nchars reached? we are done
            if ( ncharsFixed ) {
                break;
            }
            // alloc-ahead _nchars reached? grow buffer size and keep going
            if ( _nchars > (INT_MAX - _nchars - 1) ) { // guard int overflow
                free( buf );
                DBGMSG( "(_nchars=%d) *= 2 would overflow \n", _nchars );
                errno = ERANGE;
                goto fail;
            }
            _nchars *= 2;
            char *tmpbuf = realloc( buf, _nchars+1 );
            if ( !tmpbuf ) {
                free( buf );
                DBGMSG( "failed to realloc %d bytes\n", _nchars+1 );
                goto fail;
            }
            buf = tmpbuf;
        }
        buf[i++] = c;
    }
    // line longer than *nchars? Put back the last unprocessed c, so subsequent
    // function call will not skip it. NOTE: when in alloc-ahead mode the loop
    // stops ONLY after reading EOL or EOF, thus the following if-check fails.
    if ( c != '\n' && c != EOF ) {
        ungetc(c, fp);
        if ( flush ) {          // if specified, also flush extra chars
            for (int ch; (ch=fgetc(fp)) != '\n' && ch != EOF;)
                ;
        }
    }
    // if specified, append EOL
    if ( eolend ) {
        buf[i++] = '\n';
    }
    buf[i] = '\0';              // nul-terminator

    // At this point, should we realloc() buf to its exact size?
    // if ( !ncharsFixed && i < _nchars) {
        // char *tmpbuf = realloc(buf, _nchars+1);
        // if ( tmpbuf ) {
                // buf = tmpbuf;
        // }
    // }

    if ( nchars ) {             // pass to caller # of read chars
        *nchars = i;
    }
    return buf;

fail:
    if ( nchars ) {
        *nchars = 0;
    }
    return NULL;
}
```

### Details

```
char *fgetline_alloc( FILE *fp, bool flush, int *nchars, bool eolend );
```

**Arguments:**

**fp**: (`FILE *`) An already opened input text-stream (it may be `stdin`).

**flush**: (`bool`) `true` if extra `char`s should be flushed when the line to be read is longer than positive `*nchars`. It is ignored when `*nchars` is negative or 0 (see below). In most cases it should be `false`, but setting it to `true` can help in validating interactive input with a loop.

**nchars**: (`int *`) Pointer to an integer specifying either a fixed count of `char`s to be read, or an initial alloc-ahead size (in `char`s). When non-`NULL`, it passes-back the count of successfully read `chars`, excluding `nul-terminator` (0 on error). Passing `*nchars` as 0, or `nchars` as `NULL`, enables alloc-ahead mode with default initial size (128 chars). To enable alloc-ahead mode with a different initial size, pass `*nchars` with a negative value (see examples). In alloc-ahead mode the initial size auto-grows (doubled) if need be. Also, in alloc-ahead mode the `flush` argument is ignored by the function.

**eolend**: (`bool`) Determines if the returned c-string will end with EOL (`true`) or not (`false`). When looping the function to read multiple lines, this arg helps in getting consistent results regardless of the stream's last line, which may or may not end with EOL (it may end with just `EOF`).

**Remarks:**

1. **Failed** calls of the function can be identified by checking its return value against `NULL`, or by checking the updated `*nchars` value against 0. `errno` is also set either directly by the function or implicitly by the C  runtime, thus the caller may additionally use     `perror()`.
2. There is **no "partial success"**, meaning that even if partial data have been successfully read when an error occurs, they are discarded and the function fails.
3. Valid domain for `*nchars` is [`INT_MIN`+2 to `INT_MAX`-2] inclusive, but memory allocation may be denied for extreme values. If so, the function fails and a subsequent call to `perror()` will report *"not enough space"*, or similar.
4. When `eolend` is `true` and `*nchars` is positive (fixed allocation), lines longer than `*nchars` are truncated to `*nchars`, followed by EOL as an **extra** `char`.

   For example, when:

   ```
    int nchars = 2;
    char *str = fgetline_alloc(stdin, flush, &nchars, true);
   ```

   and then feeding `stdin` with "12345", will set str to "12\n". Thus the passed-back value of `nchars` willbe **3** (not the original 2).

### Sample Usage Examples

**With Text Files:**

```
/* C99 */

// prep
char *input = NULL;
int nchars;
bool flush = true;
bool eolend = true;      // always EOL (false or !eolend means: never EOL)

// Read every line of a text-file, ensuring EOL and outputting the line along with its length

FILE *fp = fopen( "in.txt", "r" );    // any text file
if ( fp ) {
    nchars = 0;          // default alloc-ahead (also causes flush to get ignored)
    while ( (input = fgetline_alloc(fp, !flush, &nchars, eolend)) ) {
        printf( "(%u/%d): %s", strlen(input), nchars, input );
        free( input );
        nchars = 0;      // reset for next call
    }
    fclose( fp );
}

// Store up to MAXLINES lines of a text-file in a custom array of lines, rejecting EOLs

struct Line {
    char *data;
    int len;
} lines[MAXLINES+1] = {{NULL,-1}};    // assuming proper MAXLINES (+1 for sentinel)

FILE *fp = fopen( "in.txt", "r" );    // any text file
if ( fp ) {
    int i = 0;            // lines counter
    nchars = -256;        // 256 chars alloc-ahead (also causes flush to get ignored)
    while ( i < MAXLINES
    && (input=fgetline_alloc(fp, !flush, &nchars, !eolend)) ) {
        printf( "Adding line[%d] (%d chars): %s\n", i, nchars, input );
        lines[i].data = input;
        lines[i].len = nchars;
        nchars = -256;    // reset for next call
        i++;
    }
    fclose( fp );
    printf( "%d lines read\n", i );
    lines[i].len = -1;  // sentinel for lines array
}
// verify and cleanup lines array
for (int i=0; lines[i].len > -1 && i < MAXLINES; i++) {
    printf( "Line[%d] (%d chars): %s\n", i, lines[i].len, lines[i].data );
    free(  lines[i].data );
    lines[i].data = NULL;
    lines[i].len = -1;
}
```

**With `stdin` (Interactive Input):**

```
/* C99 */

/* Omitting proper checking and freeing for brevity */

// prep
char *input;
int nchars;
bool flush = true;       // flush if line is longer than non-zero positive nchars
bool eolend = true;      // always EOL (false or !eolend means: never EOL)

// Read up to 100 chars (strip EOL, flush extra chars)
nchars = 100;
input = fgetline_alloc(stdin, flush, &nchars, !eolend);

// Read whole line with default alloc-ahead (strip EOL, ignore flush)
nchars = 0;              // also causes flush to get ignored
input = fgetline_alloc(stdin, flush, &nchars, !eolend);

// Read whole line with 64 chars alloc-ahead (strip EOL, ignore flush)
nchars = -64;            // intentionally negative (also causes flush to get ignored)
input = fgetline_alloc(stdin, flush, &nchars, !eolend);

/* Using proper checking and freeing */

// Validation loop (32 chars alloc-ahead, strip EOL, ignore flush)
puts( "Enter phrases (\"end\" without quotes to stop):");
for (;;) {
    nchars = -32;        // intentionally negative (also causes flush to get ignored)
    input = fgetline_alloc(stdin, flush, &nchars, !eolend);
    if ( !input ) {
        perror( "*** fgetline_alloc() failed" );
        break;
    }
    if (input && 0 == strcmp(input, "end") ) {
        free( input );
        break;
    }
    printf( "  %d chars in \"%s\"\n", nchars, input );
    free( input );
}
```

Comment: Welcome to Code Review! Please do not update the code in your question to incorporate feedback from answers, doing so goes against the Question + Answer style of Code Review. This is not a forum where you should keep the most updated version in your question. Please see [What should I do when someone answers my question?](https://codereview.stackexchange.com/help/someone-answers) as well as  [_what you may and may not do after receiving answers_](http://codereview.meta.stackexchange.com/a/1765).

Comment: @SᴀᴍOnᴇᴌᴀm, thank you for rolling it back and apologies for my ignorance. I did read the general guidelines before posting, but I apparently missed the ones you just linked to (going over them as we speak).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The macro is a little over-complex.  If we're happy to always provide a string literal as format specifier (and we should be, for debugging), then just concatenate the prefix:

```
#define DBGMSG(format, ... )\
    fprintf(stderr, "*** %s(): " format, __func__, __VA_ARGS__ )
```

Now it's a single expression, we no longer need the `do … while(0)` wrapper, and can use the return value normally.

---

Using the sign of one argument to switch behaviours is an awkward design choice.  It's too easy for an arithmetic error to cause an unintended switch of mode instead of a more visible, and thus correctable, error (either a log message or failure to allocate).

I would prefer to see an extra `bool` parameter (or more likely a "flags" argument where we can OR together named constants for the options - that's more readable at call sites).  We could possibly abstract that behind a pair of clearly-named wrapper functions that then form the main public interface, but given the other switches, I wouldn't do that (we'd need 8 functions already to cover all the flag combinations).

---

> ```
>     int _nchars = 128;
> ```

Avoid identifiers with leading underscores, even if you do happen to know the tricky details of what you can legally use in every given context, and what's reserved for the implementation.

In any case, please don't name a variable so similarly to a formal parameter - it causes no end of confusion.

Comment: Thank you for taking the time Toby, I appreciate it! I already up-voted your reply and edited my post according to your suggestions, but please allow me a few more days in case anyone else shows up. I mean before accepting it! Btw, any thoughts about the 3 bullets in my post?

Comment: I didn't have time for a really in-depth review, but saw nothing else odd during a quick skim - so don't accept this answer unless you really get nothing else!  No comments on your specific questions - I think your approaches to all three are at least as good as the choices I would have made.  Perhaps continuing to use a multiplier of 2 is getting a bit crazy when the size gets very large - perhaps switch to linear growth at some threshold?

Comment: Just saw your edit Toby, thanks! No doubt, signedness is indeed an awkward choice. I debated among several approaches (even having 2 separate funcs). Tbh I'm not very fond of `bool` params; I think they severely hurt readability when passed as direct values instead of named entities (toggled when needed). And there's 2 of them already. I prefer a flags bitmask instead too, but would require interfacing bit constants. Still not sure which of the 2 is easier from the user pov. If the func goes into a lib, `flags` makes much more sense, along with specialized negative error-codes via `nchars`.

Comment: `perhaps switch to linear growth at some threshold?`, I like this, thank you!

Comment: I would definitely go with the flags bits - it's much easier to both read and write a combination of nice named constants than a sequence of bools when you can never remember which is which.  When I wrote "more likely" in the parentheses, I really meant "_much much_ more likely"...

Comment: Yeap, bit flags instead of multiple `bool`s is a no-brainer (also one of the reasons I separated `flush` and `eolend` to opposite sides of `nchars` in the params list, being a tiny bit easier to remember compared to being sequentially listed). When I said *"not sure which of the 2 is easier from a user pov"* I meant a "library-like" implementation with interface dependencies (custom constants, errors, etc) VS the "free-roaming" one I posted here (no dependencies, but unconventional usage). Still debating (I'll probably end up doing both).

Comment: I'd not heard that "library-like" term before, but that's what I would go for.  It's not like there's a significant cost to declaring a few constants in addition to the function.

Comment: That was just a coined up term, not a real one, meaning the need for some kind of supporting interface in-order to use the function. I accepted the answer since no-one stepped in. Thanks again for a good review Toby!